# How to make a div rendered on a particular event in lightning?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I wanna make my popup to appear only when a record is clicked ? How can I achieve the same,I wanna show the details of that particular record in popup screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to display details in a jQuery dialog.
On clicking the record, get the id of the record and display the details.

Also you can use force:navigateToSobject event to go to the detail page of the record.

[Check here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm)

Comment: You are welcome @ShobhitSaxena